Laravel migrations create table column with dot in colum name
I have a table in SQL Server database where a column has a dot in its name. When I first created manually the table I had no problems doing it, but now that I'm changing the db server I decided to recreate the db structure using migrations and here comes the problem: I can't create the columns with a dot in the name.
If I write
public function up()
{
    Schema::connection('ConnectionName')->create('table', function(Blueprint $table) {
        $table->id();
        $table->boolean('Active');
        $table->string('Table2.Column1')->nullable();
        $table->string('Table2.Column2')->nullable();
        $table->string('Table3.Column1')->nullable();
    });
}

and run the migration I get an error because the commands get converted in SQL like
create table "table" (
"id" bigint identity primary key not null, 
"Active" bit not null, 
"Table2"."Column1" nvarchar(255) null, 
"Table2"."Column2" nvarchar(255) null, 
"Table3"."Column1" nvarchar(255) null
)

As you can see the columns with the dot in the name have a double quotes around the dot, is there any way?

I can't say I've ever used . in a column name, but considering that most SQL flavours use . as a separator between Schema/Database, table and column, like MySchema.MyTable.MyColumn, you could maybe try a different convention, like Table2_Column1, or Table2Column1, etc. My question then becomes "do you need to use Table2.Column1 as the column name"?

I found a workaround, I'm going to post the solution in a comment.

My bad, I was referring to that section. However the column names of this table are used to create a dynamic sql query that in the select would have the Table2.Column1 and a join to Table2. Don't know if I was clear enough, it's quite tricky.

No worries! I think I see what you're doing, and all good re: comments vs answer section. . does seem to be supported in Column Names, but I think you'd have to reference it as something like [ConnectionName].[Table2.Column1] in SqlServer, which might not natively work in Laravel. DB::statement() and DB::raw() can be used to get around this, but depending on how heavily you're using this naming convention, you might be making more work for yourself. Either way, glad you got this sorted out for the Migration

As a workaround I used the
DB::statement()

method to run a raw DDL command to create the table.
